# IOS Universal link works in notes but not in browser

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have a universal link that does not work properly. Lets say the link is domain.com/sub. We have set up in xcode the associated domain "domain.com". We have set up /.well-known/apple-app-site-association.json correctly on our server.

If I click the link domain.com/sub in a notepad, text message or any other app it will correctly switch to the app **however** if I click an a-tag on our website which redirects to href=domain.com/nudge it will instead open the link.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue? We have tried both chrome + safari on iOS 16.

We've tried making sure that the link is absolute and not relative for the a-tag but there's no change.

Edit: The issue is that it uses the same domain and universal links do not support same domain, it is intended behavior.

Comment: Universal links do not work in Chrome, Brave, Firefox etc on iOS but they do work in Safari. In your question you give two different paths `/sub` and `/nudge`. Was that a typo or do you have two different paths?  Is the second path included in your site association file?  You can test universal links under the developer menu in iOS. I also suggest you generate a sysdiagnose file on your device and download it. You can then check the universal link file that you device has.

Comment: Hi, we figured out the issue. The issue is that it links to the same domain (previously we had another domain which is why it worked then).

It works fine on chrome with universal links.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, same here and I think this is by design. It's the OS (and the OS only) that knows which links are associated with your app, and the browser is not sending links for evaluation to the OS. If you click a deeplink in another app however, it delegates it to the OS to either open the default browser or your app.

Edit: You may want to check out [Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners) and/or [Custom URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app)

An untested solution that might work along with a custom URL scheme is this [workaround through JS timeout](https://gist.github.com/mcxiaoke/c2dd7d24c31c5bd2d724)

Comment: Our first solution was a smart app banner but it was removed because of how it looks. We're using a custom banner. The idea is that the link sends you to a page that redirects you to the app store so if you do not have the app it will go to the app store and if you have it will intercept it and open the app.

Comment: I get the point, but unfortunately there's so safe way on iOS to check whether an app is currently installed or not. You could, however, add a custom URL scheme and try the workaround I've added to my answer above.

Comment: so I realized the issue was that universal links respect the same domain. If we link to another domain it will work fine.